# selfhosted Gitlab timeout internal network

Tags: gitlab

I installed gitlab on an ubuntu server

I have a domain, here I made a cname entry that points to my noip name. no ip is set up on my router, ports 80 and port 443 are also forwarded to my server.

I can access my gitlab server from outside via this domain, but it doesn't work in the same network as the server, I get a timeout message, sometimes the login page comes up, but very slowly.

Why isn't this working? Can it be that the domain in the internal network is not routed to the outside?